# It is possible to get tuple value without use the property?

Tags: c#

```
public (string Name, int Length) GetData() {
   return ("Test", 12);
}
```

so is that possible that I can just use

```
string Name = GetData();
```

or

```
var value = GetData();
if(value.Length == 12)
   return GetData();
```

I know I can use it like this

```
var value = GetData();
if(value.Length == 12)
   return value.Name;
```

but I dont want to use the propterty every time

Comment: What would `return GetData()` or `string Name = GetData()` do? If your tuple was `(string A, string B)`, which would it choose?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica I want that I only can use return `GetData()` to only return the string but also to use the other property

Comment: You're missing the point: the compiler isn't psychic. If I have `public (string A, string B) GetData()`, then what does `return GetData()` return?

Comment: oh okay I thought it was possible like `public string (string A, int Length) GetData()`

Comment: You can do string Name = GetData().Name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can almost do it by using tuple deconstruction.

In your case, you can do

```cs
var (name, length) = GetData();
if(length == 12)
   return name;
```

Comment: much better thanxs :D